# how to insert a button to open modal window inside a simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form, bootstrap-modal

using Rails 4.1.6 , simple_form 3.1.0.rc2, Bootstrap 3
I am trying to set a button inside my simple_form to open a Bootsrap modal window to perform a js user selection

my simple form is the following :

```
.form-inputs
  .row
    .col-sm-8.col-md-8.col-lg-8
        - if ((current_user.has_role? :superadmin) || (current_user.has_role? :media_admin)) 
            .form-group
                %button.btn.btn-default{:'data-toggle' => "modal" , :'data-target' => "#myModal"}
                    Select Owner of album
        = f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: current_user.id}

  .row
    .col-sm-8.col-md-8.col-lg-8
        = f.input :title, :label => t(:title, scope: :album).capitalize
        = f.input :description, as: :text, :label => t(:description, scope: :album).capitalize
```

and I added a  standard bootstrap modal test

```
            #myModal.modal.fade{ tabindex: "-1" ,role: "dialog", :'aria-labelledby' => "myModalLabel",  :'aria-hidden' => "true"}
            .modal-dialog
                .modal-content
                    .modal-header
                        %button.close{type: "button",  :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
                            %span{:'aria-hidden' => true}
                                &times;
                            %span.sr-only
                                Close
                        %h4#myModalLabel.modal-title
                            Modal Title
                    .modal-body
                        = "Modal body"
                    .modal-footer
                        %button.btn.btn-default{type: "button",  :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
                            Close
                        %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "button",  :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
                            Save changes
```

When I hit the 'Select Owner of album' button, it acts as the submit one and try to save the form data.... not opening the modal form

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Facing the same, any improvements?

Answer (score 1):

I should rather use a link tag with button class....

```
                .form-group
                %a.btn.btn-success{href: "#", :'data-toggle' => "modal" , :'data-target' => "#myModal"}
                    Select Owner of album
```